# jQuery Search page for word not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, panels

I have a view full of [bootstrap collapsible panels](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse.asp).  Inside the panels are a list of documents.  I have a search box at the top of the page for the user to type in the document name.

**What currently happens**

When the user types in the name of a document and presses enter.. if a match is found.. the panel that contains the document does not expand, but if I click on it, then it expands and shows me the document that matched... the rest of the panels are still visible but do not open because they don't have any matches.

**What I want to happen**

What I want to happen is if a match is found then hide the panels and documents that don't have a match.  When the clear search button is clicked to bring back all panels and documents (like a page refresh but I do not want a refresh).

**Here is my code**

> **Search Box**

```
<div id="Search-Section">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="text" id="SearchLink" class="form-control link-search" placeholder="Document Name..." style="margin-left: 36%;"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="submit" value="Search" id="ButtonSearch" class="btn btn-default SearchButtons" style="float: right; margin-right: -2%;"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="reset" value="Clear Search" id="ButtonClearSearch" class="btn btn-default SearchButtons" style="margin-left: -69%;"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> **Collapsible Panel Example**

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 2%;">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="panel-group">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">Panel One</a>
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="~/Docs/testdoc1.pdf" target="_blank">Test Document 1</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="panel-group">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse2">Panel Two</a>
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="~/Docs/testdoc2.pdf" target="_blank">Test Document 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="~/Docs/testdoc3.pdf" target="_blank">Test Document 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="~/Docs/testdoc4.doc" target="_blank">Test Document 4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="~/Docs/testdoc5.doc" target="_blank">Test Document 5</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**So when I search for 'Test Document 1'.. then Panel Two should be completely hidden, but when I click 'Clear Search' button then Panel Two should be brought back along with Panel One (even though Panel One wasn't hidden because it contained a document that matched the search).**

> **jQuery**

```
// When user wants to search for document

$("#SearchLink").keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        var textboxValue = $("#SearchLink").val().toLowerCase();
        alert(textboxValue);
        $('.panel-body').each(function () {
            var exist = false;
            $(this).find('ul li').each(function () {
                if ($(this).find('a').text().toLowerCase().indexOf(textboxValue) !== -1) {
                    $(this).show();
                    exist = true;
                } else
                    $(this).hide();
            });
            if (exist === false) {
                $(this).prev('.panel-title').hide();
                $(this).hide();
            } else {
                $(this).prev('.panel-title').show();

            }
        });
    }
});

// When user wants to clear search

$("#ButtonClearSearch").click(function () {
    $("#SearchLink").val("");

    $('.panel-body').each(function() {
        $(this).prev('h4').show();
        $(this).children().each(function() {
            $('ul li').show();
            $('a').show();
        });
    });
    $('#SearchLink').blur(function() {
        if ($.trim(this.value) == null) {
            $(this).val($(this).attr('Document Search'));

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Just a hint: Instead of alert() you can use console.log() and look at the log in the console tab of the "inspect element" browser tool. More quick to work on.

Comment: I know that, but I just wanted to see the value.. so I used alert to avoid more button clicks to get to the console tab.

Comment: You have anyway to click the button to close the alert, while the console stays open for the next refreshes. Just an hint though.

Comment: Indeed.  I develop my pages with the console open full time - reduces clicks, actually... and, you can actually _see_ the contents of arrays an objects in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `$(this).show();` try to show the [parent](https://api.jquery.com/parents/):

```
$(this).parents('.collapse').show();
```

or

```
$(this).parents('.collapse').addClass('in');
```

the script will like this:

```js
$(function(){
 $("#SearchLink").keyup(function (event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13)
   search($(this).val());
 });

 $('#ButtonSearch').click(function(){
  search($("#SearchLink").val());
 })
 
 function search(keyword){
  var textboxValue = keyword.toLowerCase();
  $('.panel-body').each(function () {
   var exist = false;
   $(this).find('ul li').each(function () {
    if ($(this).find('a').text().toLowerCase().indexOf(textboxValue) !== -1) {
     exist = true;
    }
   });
   if (exist === false) {
    $(this).parent().removeClass('in');
   } else {
    $(this).parent().addClass('in');
   }
  });
 }
 
 // When user wants to clear search

 $("#ButtonClearSearch").click(function () {
  $("#SearchLink").val("");
  $('.panel-body').each(function() {
   $(this).parent().removeClass('in');
  });
  $('#SearchLink').blur(function() {
   if ($.trim(this.value) == null) {
    $(this).val($(this).attr('Document Search'));

   }
  });
 });
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="Search-Section">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="text" id="SearchLink" class="form-control link-search" placeholder="Document Name..." />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="submit" value="Search" id="ButtonSearch" class="btn btn-default SearchButtons" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="reset" value="Clear Search" id="ButtonClearSearch" class="btn btn-default SearchButtons" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row" style="margin-top: 2%;">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="panel-group">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">Panel One</a>
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="~/Docs/testdoc1.pdf" target="_blank">Test Document 1</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="panel-group">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse2">Panel Two</a>
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="~/Docs/testdoc2.pdf" target="_blank">Test Document 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="~/Docs/testdoc3.pdf" target="_blank">Test Document 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="~/Docs/testdoc4.doc" target="_blank">Test Document 4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="~/Docs/testdoc5.doc" target="_blank">Test Document 5</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does this do?  Is that all I should do?  I tried it, but it results in same behavior unless I'm missing something.

Comment: This was for expanding the matched panel, can't guess why it's not working. Is the value of `exist` set to "true", when you insert a correct match?

Comment: I forgot to add the `.` before the `collapse` class call. It seems to work now, have a look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bt1LyLoz/1/)

Comment: Okay, that is expanding the panel, but hiding the document name for me.

Comment: Nvmd, I was using the 1st answer you gave but switched to the second and that worked.

Comment: So in the example you provided.  If I type in Document 2.. then panel two expands and shows me document 2.. perfect.. but when I want to hit the clear search button.. how do I get all documents to be restored but the containing panel to be collapsed?

Comment: i add example based on @T30 answer. and that's works fine for your case

Comment: @T30: yes boss (^_^)7 LOL. GTown-Coder: give your thanks to T30 haha